# How to access admin from doccano deployed using heroku

Tags: heroku, admin, doccano

I had a local docanno running in desktop. On it I was able to add new users for collaborative annotation , who can access the doccano app from LAN. Now I want to deploy the app to web, so annotators can access it from anywhere. But when I deploy doccano on heroku, I m not able to access the admin through the app. It says page not found , if I try to do .herokuapp.com/admin/
How to add collobarots , through heroku deployed doccano app.

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick fix I found on https://bytemeta.vip/repo/doccano/doccano/issues/1814 :

1. On Heroku, go to settings
2. Add the Config Var "DEBUG" with the value set to "True"
3. I was then able to access the admin pane, add users etc (url: https://{appname}.herokuapp.com/admin).
4. Set the value to "False"